# Ideal number Actor Systems in a project

Tags: akka

We are creating a web project, I just want to ask what is the ideal number of Actor System in a project? Thanks. I'm using akka btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 instance per logical application. ActorSystems are rather heavyweight compared to "normal" objects and create Threads.

Comment: Thanks. In the current setup of our project, we're encountering problems actors, do you think it's because we have a lot of actor system going on?

Comment: It's impossible to answer that question with the given information.